# Derived function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

Could the derived function $ f'$ have a domain different from the domain of $f$ ?
For example, could we say that the derived function of modulus function is the function $ f' $ : $ \Bbb R $ $\setminus$ {0} $\rightarrow$ $ \Bbb R $ (since the modulus function is not differentiable at $x = 0 $) that is $1$ when $x>0$ and $-1$ when $x<0$ ? If so, is the modulus function of class $C^1$ ? Does it implies that the only functions that are not of class $C^1$ are functions nowhere differentiable? If not, could someone give me a counterexample?

Comment: Hint: you can consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: In fact, the function $ \frac{1}{2 sqrt(x)} $ is not defined at 0. So modulus function (and square root function) really has a "derived function", even if it is not differentiable. And they're both of class $ C^1 $.